# SVN special symbol stands for?

Tags: url, svn, semantics, symbols

for SVN, what does the symbol ^ stand for?

```
  svn merge ^/feature
  svn merge ^/trunk
```

Is it the root URL of current project? or repository root file path? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caret (at the start of a URL) is equivalent to one starting at the root of the repository:

> In Subversion 1.6, a new caret (^) notation was introduced as a shorthand for "the URL of the repository's root directory".

See more information about it [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls).

Comment: Thanks. ^^ on windows.

Comment: @Dave, on Windows, it's still `^`, it just happens that the "batch command language" implemented by `cmd.exe` treats `^` as the line continuation character, and so if you want it to be not interpreted in a command, you have to escape it--by prepending it with another `^`--yielding `^^`. The Subversion's `svn` command will actually see just a single caret symbol because the escaping one will be stripped out by the shell.